# most different human tissues with respect to gene expression profiling

Tags: human-biology, gene, tissue

Is there a PCA showing the relative distance in terms of gene expression / functional genomics among the different human tissue types?

So far I have found:

(1) A paper based on gene expression with some tissues/tissue groups, not many:
https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2010-11-12-r124

(2) A paper based on gene expression signatures and aging:
https://www.nature.com/articles/npjamd201614/figures/1

(3) A paper on Gene and Protein Expression in Normal and Cancer Tissues:
https://www.nature.com/articles/srep24799/figures/3

Comment: Assuming you know what distance measure you want to use, I think the best approch is download a tissue data set such as GTEX yourself and compute the pairwise distance matrix. If you're a bioinformatics person this is should be straightforward. PCA projection to 2D (or even 3D) is only an approximation of the actual pairwise distances, and for tissue gene expression that approximation tends to be poor, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate the GTEX project. PCA section.

https://www.gtexportal.org/home/histologyPage?tab=PCA

You have different samples for many tissues. Currently you can navigate it tissue by tissue but perhaps there's a way of visualizing the whole dataset (or you can ask for it).

Comment: The website looks very promising, but it seems, as you say, that you can only PCA tissue by tissue.